# How to create api endpoint to create super user in django

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Hey i have one question about creating superuser with djangorestframework.
I want to create superuser with POST request using DRF 3.14

How should i do that if i'm using Android as a client for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know what you are doing (superusers are quite powerful in Django), I suggest you include the following snippet in your DRF view:

```py
from django.core import management

management.call_command('createsuperuser', **yourargs)
```

Full documentation can be found in the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code)